# Android: Why use imagebutton?

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

Warning: I am a noob so this might not be a "regular question".

My question:
Instead of using an imagebutton in Android isnt it the same to use an image, make clickable=true and then use that onClick as well?

Isnt that the same? Or am I missing something?

The only thing my google ventures has given me is that you can have different states onPressed, onReleased etc but that too can easily be done via the java code.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: An image is not part of the view class, but imagebutton is. You may find some use in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203650/what-is-use-of-image-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageButton gives you more control on how to display the image than if you were using the base View class.